# Loop with curl seen as one connection

Tags: php, curl

Hi I'm parsing a website (SHOP) with this script:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
set_time_limit(120);
require_once '../../../simple_html_dom.php';    
require_once'../../../functions.php';
echo '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">';
echo "Beginning import at: ".date('H').":".date('i')."\n";
mysql_connect ("localhost","xxxx","xxxx"); 
mysql_select_db ("sklepy"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARSET utf8'); 
$sklepy=(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ps_supplier` where id_supplier = 3"));
do {
$curl = curl_init();
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$timeout = 5;
$cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false ); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $adres);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
 curl_close($curl);
 /code for extracting data from DOM
}

while ($limit != $sklep['limit']); 

}
?>
```

And I'm having problem that every loop of that do {} is seen as new connection to parsing server, and after ~5min it shows that there is 1000 persons online,
How to change the code to imitate one long connection?
PS. sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php for that. There are some working examples